# How to avoid creating relationships which result in cycle in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Is there a way to create constraint in neo4j such that it avoid creating cycles/loops between nodes in neo4j

```
I have four nodes A,B,C,D  and relationship between them as 
A->B
B->C
C->D
now a relationship from
D->A will create as cycle .  But i want to throw error if i try to create a relationship from D->A




CREATE (a:TEST {name:'A'})
CREATE (b:TEST {name:'B'})
CREATE (c:TEST {name:'C'})
CREATE (d:TEST {name:'D'})
CREATE (e:TEST {name:'E'})
create (a)-[:REL]->(b)
create (b)-[:REL]->(c)
create (c)-[:REL]->(d)
create (d)-[:REL]->(e)
return a,b,c,d,e
```

Inserting Nodes and creating relationships. 
After that

```
MATCH (d:TEST {name:'E'}), (a:TEST {name:'A'})
WHERE NOT exists((a)-[:REL*]->(d))
WITH d, a
  CREATE (d)-[:REL]->(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nop, there is no such constrainst in Neo4j.

But before to create the relationship you can check if path exists between `A` & `D`.  And if it is not the case, you create the relationship.

Something like that :

```
MATCH (d:Node {value:'d'}), (a:Node {value:'a')
WHERE NOT exists((a)-[:MY_REL*]->(d))
WITH d, a
  CREATE (d)-[:MY_REL]->(a)
```

Comment: I need, if the creation of relationship between nodes will results in cycle or not. Above query checks whether relationship exists between the nodes.

Comment: Oups sorry I forgot to add the cardinality on the relationship with the `*` . I have updated my answer.

Comment: That didn't worked. It created a relationship that created cycle

Comment: can you share the query you used ? (because I think you have adapted mine). Normally with my query it's not possible to create a cycle for the relationship type `MY_REL`.

Comment: I updated your question with the valid cypher query. It's just due to the direction of the relationship inside the exist.

Comment: But (a)-[:MY_REL*]->(d) doesn't result in cycle . But d->a result in cycle.